# Merge same keys in one list values in dict

Tags: reactjs, arrays, dictionary

I am building a blog app in react and I am filtering some dict values and appending in list dict. But It is appending duplicate keys with unique values in list dict. And I am know trying to merge the two same keys into one But I have tried many times but it is not working.

App.js

```
function App(response) {
  var filteredResponse = []

  response.forEach(function (element) {
    for (let i = 0; i < blogTypes.length; i++) {
      if (element['type'] === blogTypes[i]) {
        filteredResponse.push({type: blogTypes[i], data : element})
      }
    }
  })

  console.log(filteredResponse);

  return null;
}
```

It is showing

```
[
  {
      "type": "Wellness",
      "blog_title": "First Blog",
  },
  {
      "type": "Writing",
      "blog_title": "Second Blog",

  },
  {
      "type": "Wellness",
      "blog_title": "Third Blog",

  },
  {
      "type": "Health",
      "blog_title": "Fourth Blog",
  }
]
```

**And I am trying to get like**

```
[
  {
    "type": "Wellness",
    "blogs": [
            "First Blog", 
            "Third Blog"
      ]
  },
  {
    "type": "Writing",
    "blogs": [
            "Second Blog", 
      ]
  },
  {
    "type": "Health",
    "blogs": [
            "Fourth Blog", 
      ]
  },
]
```

I have tried using :-

```
const map = new Map(filteredResponse.map(({ blog_title, type }) => [blog_title, { blog_title, type: [] }]));
for (let { blog_title, type } of multipleFilteredResponse) map.get(blog_title).type.push(...[type].flat());

console.log([...map.values()]);
```

But it reterned

```
[
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "type": "Wellness",
        "blog_title": "First Blog",
      },
      {
        "type": "Writing",
        "blog_title": "Second Blog",

      },
      {
        "type": "Wellness",
        "blog_title": "Third Blog",

      },
      {
        "type": "Health",
        "blog_title": "Fourth Blog",
      }
    ]
  },
  department : undefined
]
```

I have tried many times but it is still not working. Any help would be much Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is the original input from your response, but here is how you can turn data in your first code block into the second one you wanted.

```js
// Online Javascript Editor for free
// Write, Edit and Run your Javascript code using JS Online Compiler

filteredResponse = [
  {
      "type": "Wellness",
      "blog_title": "First Blog",
  },
  {
      "type": "Writing",
      "blog_title": "Second Blog",

  },
  {
      "type": "Wellness",
      "blog_title": "Third Blog",

  },
  {
      "type": "Health",
      "blog_title": "Fourth Blog",
  }
]

const map = new Map(filteredResponse.map(({ blog_title, type }) => [type, { type, blogs: [] }]));

for (let { type, blog_title } of filteredResponse) map.get(type).blogs.push(blog_title);

console.log([...map.values()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start with an object instead of an array:

```
const blogByTypes = {};


response.forEach(response => {
    if (blogByTypes[response.type]) {
        blogByTypes[response.type].blogs.push(response.blog_title);
    } else {
        blogByTypes[response.type] = {blogs: [response.blog_title]};
    }
});
```

You can then extract the entries:

```
const result = Object.entries(blogByTypes);
```

Comment: What is `blogByTypes` ? And What's store in it ? Did you remove `for loop` inside the `forEach` ?

Comment: Your for loop is weird as you're looping through an array and only keeping the value when it matches response.type so it looks like it's useless.

Comment: I've created an object blogByTypes to store for each types the blog entries

Comment: But What is `blogByTypes[response.type]` returning ?, which is empty